# An airline knows that 5% of the people who make reservations for a given flight do not show up.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

An airline knows that 5% of the people who make reservations for a given flight do not show up. Consequently, its policy is to sell 52 tickets for a flight that can accommodate 50 people. What is the probability that a seat will be available for all the passengers who show up?

I have already solved the exercise, but I have a doubt: The probability that a passenger does not show up (the probability of failure) is 1-p=0.05?

Comment: You haven't introduced or defined $p$ yet. But you are correct that if $E_i$ is the event that the $i$th passenger does not show up, then the probability that the event $E_i$ occurs is $.05$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: See [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}$.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the problem carefully.

Question: Experience shows that $20%$ of the people reserving tables at a certain restaurant never show up. If the restaurant has 50 tables and takes 52 reservations, then what is the probability that it will be able to accommodate everyone?

Solution:

$50$ tables can accommodate $50$ men. But they have taken $52$ reservations.

The restaurant will be able to accommodate everyone, if 50 men or fewer men show up.
Everyone gets a seat when $(X \leq 50)$.
To find this, we use the complement rule.
$1 -$ [Find the chance, Too many men show up with $X = 51$ OR $X = 52$]

Given : 20% of people don't show up. Then,  Success : Men who show up : $p = 80  $% and Failure : Men who didn't show up : $(1-p) = 1 - 80/100 = 20/100$

$\Pr(X \leq 50) = 1 - \Pr(X > 50) = 1 - \sum_{k = 51}^{52} \binom{52}{k}(0.8)^k(0.2)^{52 - k} = 1-[P(X = 51) + P(X = 52)]= 1- [\binom{52}{51}(0.8)^{51}(1 - 0.8)^{52 - 51} + \binom{52}{52}(0.8)^{52}(1 - 0.8)^{52 - 52} ]$

Comment: Careful. If 20 never show up then you can just take 70 reservations. What you have is that any person reserving turns up with some probability p, and you claim that with r reservations, p = 1 - 20/r. There’s the problem that they are not independent. If four people book together then most likely all or none turn up.